# Change row colour based on value in previous row

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, colors

I have an excel file with an ID field.  The ID field is not unique to each row, instead, in some cases, it is repeated on subsequent rows.  I want to format the cells so that row colour changes with the ID field changes:

Example:

```
ID
1 - white
1 - white
2 - blue
3 - white
4 - blue
4 - blue
4 - blue
```

Any suggestions for writing a conditional format formula that will do this?

Comment: I cannot see what the logic is in your example? how do you determine what colour the row is going to be, is it just even vs odd?

Comment: @JustinDoward I was just alternating between the two colours when the ID # changed.

Answer (score 0):

=ISODD(MATCH(A1,UNIQUE(A:A),0))

Insert this directly into the conditional format for ""Use a formula to determine..." if you have the UNIQUE function in your version of Excel.

**Alternative non-UNIQUE function solution:**

Alternatively, you'll have to create a second column in B to generate TRUE or FALSE per grouping of IDs. The formula has to look back up one row to toggle the output if the ID has changed. Say A1 is ID and B1 is GROUP. Your IDs are A2..Axx and B2 is FALSE. Then put in B3 and copy down:

```
=IF(A2=A3,B2,NOT(B2))
```

then set a conditional format by selecting all the data (A2:Bxx), creating a new rule based on "Use a formula to determine" and enter =$B2 in the formula box. Your data will look like this:

```
ID GROUP
1  FALSE -> conditional format white
1  FALSE -> normal cell format white
2  TRUE  -> conditional format blue
3  FALSE -> normal cell format white
4  TRUE  -> conditional format blue
4  TRUE  -> conditional format blue
4  TRUE  -> conditional format blue
```

Comment: I'm not following your explanation.  Can you provide more detail?  I don't have the UNIQUE function

Comment: for example, what is B1?  I'm assuming A1 is my ID column.

Comment: A1 and B1 can be headers e.g. ID and GROUP. I'll update my solution.

Comment: Looks like you're missing an extra parenthesis at the end of the UNIQUE function