# group multiple IP ranges into respective subnets in Notepad++

Tags: networking, microsoft-excel, ip, notepad++

I am not good with coding at all, so i will need some basic answering please
I have a list of bad IP addresses some belonging in /24 subnets but each range is different.
I need to group them for easy understand and reporting,
I have listed them down in Notepad++ as well as in MS Excel, is there any way I can group them based on their /24 subnets either in EXCEL OR Notepad++

Comment: Please, [eddit your question](https://superuser.com/posts/1608145/edit) and add sample file and expected result.

Answer (score 2):

Say you have an unsorted list of IPv4's, eg.:

[image]

You can simply sort them alphanumerically:

[image]

If you want to physically group in excel with expanding / collapsing rows, add a column before your IP's called subnet, with this formula

```
=LEFT(B2,SEARCH(".",B2,1+SEARCH(".",B2,1+SEARCH(".",B2))))&"x"
```

Now select your whole table and insert a pivot table:

[image]

Comment: Alternatively, if you don't want to use pivot tables and only color coding (i.e. sorted list, all 10.1.1.x rows blue, all 10.1.2.x rows white, all 10.1.3.x rows blue), then see this question https://superuser.com/questions/1605584/change-row-colour-based-on-value-in-previous-row/

Comment: Thank you, that makes so much sense.

Comment: For spanish people use "Encontrar" instead "Buscar" in Excel: =IZQUIERDA(B2;ENCONTRAR(".";B2;1+ENCONTRAR(".";B2;1+ENCONTRAR(".";B2))))&"x"